# How to convert std::vector<char*> to char**?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a vector of c strings to an array of c strings. I tried this but it does not appear to work right:

```
int glfxGetProgramList(int effect, char** progList, int* count)
{
    std::vector<char*> list;
    gEffects[effect]->GetProgramList(list);
    fprintf(stderr, "Lib Output: %s\n", list[0]);
    progList = &list[0];
    int size = list.size();
    memcpy(count, &size, sizeof(int));
}
```

The debug output returned from stderr is correct inside the function. However, when I use this function inside my project and try to output the first item in the list it crashes with a segmentation fault. Here is the code in my project:

```
char ** list;
int size;
glfxGetProgramList(effect, list, &size );
fprintf(stderr, "Output: %s\n", list[0]);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I think I'm going to have to start at the base of the problem. There is a private map array which I'm trying to get the list of names from. Here is the code for GetProgramList:

```
unsigned Effect::GetProgramList(vector<char*>& list) const
{
    for(map<string,Program*>::const_iterator it=m_programs.begin(); it!=m_programs.end(); ++it)
        list.push_back( (char*)it->first.c_str() );
}
```

Comment: Note that `data()` is meant for this purpose since C++11.

Comment: *"does not appear to work right"* is about the least useful problem description you could have come up with.

Comment: Please provide the declaration of `GetProgramList()`.

Comment: Don't refer to the data structure in variable names. Change `list` to `program`.

Comment: -1. "Does not appear to work right" is not a valid problem description. Please [edit] your question to be more precise about what problem you're having. What did you expect to happen, and what actually happens instead?

Comment: I added more information. Before when I looked at the locals and expressions debug output the string was just wrong and I had no idea why. Now I find that when I try to use the string in my program crashes. The pointer must be wrong somehow.

Comment: Ok I think I know what is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it... The std::vector<char*> is being released when the function finishes...

Comment: You can do more. Make a template function that converts vector <T>in  T *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 progList = &list[0];
```

Should work perfectly.

But because:

```
std::vector<char*> list;
```

is local to the function it is only valid while the function is active. Once the function returns the pointer become invalid (as the vector no longer exists).

The reason I mention this is that you seem to be trying to use `progList` as an out parameters here:

```
int glfxGetProgramList(int effect, char** progList, int* count)


// Because you call like this:  
glfxGetProgramList(effect, list, &size );  // The value of list will not change
                                           // as you are passing by value.

fprintf(stderr, "Output: %s\n", list[0]);  // So here list has not changed.
                                           // But also note it would not have worked
                                           // as the object you were trying to make it 
                                           // point at would have gone out of scope.
```

Unfortunately (or fortunately) because these parameters are not references any changes you make locally do not affect the original values outside the function.

So you need to fix a couple of things:

- Make the vector last longer than the call to the function
- Pass list by reference into the function.

Try:

```
int glfxGetProgramList(int effect, char**& progList, int* count)
                               //        ^  pass by reference
{
    static std::vector<char*> list; // Static makes the list last past the end of the function
    list.clear();                   // Now we have to clear it each time we call to make sure
                                    // that old results do not pollute the list.

    gEffects[effect]->GetProgramList(list);
    fprintf(stderr, "Lib Output: %s\n", list[0]);

    progList = &list[0];       // Value now passed correctly
                               // back to the calling function
                               // and list will still exist.

    int size = list.size();
    memcpy(count, &size, sizeof(int));  // This copies the first value out
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out but do you have any ideas for a solution? Actually I think I need to post the code for GetProgramList. Editing now...

Comment: That static vector is an accident waiting to happen.  Why not simply `int glfxGetProgramList(int effect, vector<char*>& list)`?

Comment: Because then users of the library would be forced to include std::vector into their project. This is not my library I'm just helping enhance an existing library so it will work with my project. I don't want to add a new requirement that may break other people's code.

Comment: @SteveDeFacto: The memory for storing a copy these char pointers needs to come from somewhere.  You can either have the caller allocate it or the API allocate it but using a static buffer is dangerous because the user will have no idea about the lifetime of the data.  For example they may try to call this function from a different thread or access older data after calling it again (which will invalidate their previous pointers).

Answer (score 3):

You can access `char**` like so (but only if your compiler supports [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)):

```
    progList = list.data();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you casting?

The address of the first `char *` element is automatically a `char **`, no need for casting. If this is not working, post the definition of `progList`. If the vector is empty, this will result in undefined behavior and likely lead your application to crash. Be sure that `list.size()` is greater than 0 (or `!list.emty()` - better).

Comment: If the vector is empty an error will **not** be thrown (I assume you meant _exception_). It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tim obviously. Perhaps I should rephrase with "your app will throw a hissy fit?"

Comment: Why not rephrase it to read _undefined behavior_ instead of using misleading terminology. In its current form it reads as though the consequence would be deterministic. Which it isn't.